# Reshaping/Cleaning Data from horizontal form to panel form

Tags: excel, reshape, data-cleaning, vba

I do not know if this is reshaping so much as it is data cleaning (or if they are one in the same) but my problem is as such:

I have the sample raw data in this format:

[Sample Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h27km.jpg)

And the Required sample output should be of this form:

[Sample required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY9ek.jpg)

Is anyone able to assist in writing a for-loop that could do such a thing by copying the raw data and outputting it in the required format somehow?

I've spent hours with no luck..

Comment: Isn't this a standard case of `Unpivot`? Check this http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal OR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUXJLzqlEPk OR https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098 (just to link a few of them).

Comment: This is so amazing, thank you @Ralph!